# RG dimensions of composite operators

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

It has come to my attention that the RG dimensions (or anomalous dimensions) of composite operators including the same number of fields is different, in general. Lets consider a scalar N-component theory of the form
$$\mathcal{S}=\int dx^{4-\epsilon}\left(\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi_i\partial_{\mu}\phi_i+\frac{g_1\mu^{\epsilon}}{4!}(\phi_i\phi_i)^2+\frac{g_2\mu^{\epsilon}}{4!}\phi_i^2\phi_i^2\right)$$
where there exists an O(N) symmetric term and N $\phi^4$-terms. From what I understand, there is no mixing in the anomalous dimensions of the field components, so the anomalous dimension matrix is diagonal.

I also know that if one turns off the second interaction (put $g_2=0$) then the anomalous dimensions of two general composite operators that contain the same number of fields $\phi_i$ are indeed the same.

However, if one considers the full interactive model the respective anomalous dimension of the composite operator are not the same. These composite operators could have the following form, for example,
$$\phi_1^2\phi_2^3\hspace{1cm},\qquad\phi_1\phi_2^4.$$
So, I am wondering if it is wrong to write down composite operators of the form
$$\phi_1^2\phi_2^3+\phi_1\phi_2^4,.$$
due to the above dimensionality fact. In addition, I would like to know under what circumstances these operators happen to have the same anomalous dimensions. Thank you very much for any answers.

Comment: Could you clarify your notation? What is $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$? Which ordering prescription are you using for powers, Wick powers?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. The fields $\phi_i$ are simple scalar fields. I don't quite understand what you mean regarding the ordering powers. The operator $\phi_1^n$ is just the normal ordered product of n elementary $\phi_1$ operators.

Comment: "Normal ordered" answers the second part of my question thanks. What theory are you considering? How do $\phi_{1,2}$ interact with each other? Please add as much detail as possible to your question. In its present form it is unclear what you are asking..

Comment: I edited my question explaining more details. Thanks for the suggestion.